# Compounds that release carbon dioxide

Tags: home-experiment

What are some compounds that release carbon dioxide when heated, hydrated, or reacted with sodium, aluminum, silicon, or iron?

Comment: Mix baking soda with dry citric acid; that would work pretty well once it gets in contact with water.

Comment: You see, the problem with these questions is that many answers can be correct and you can't rightfully judge which single answer is the best. SE model is not good for these kind of questions and we close them as "too broad", which is what's going to happen to this question, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

A solvent such as water would be required and carbonate or bicarbonate salts will release CO2(g) when reacted with most acids.

Dry ice will turn to CO2(g) when exposed to room temperature.

These are only a couple of examples as others have stated there could be many other methods.